# How to properly display the value from a usb device [ansi c]

Tags: c, variables, integer

`printf("%d, ", packet[i]);`

How to display variable correctly. It should be from 0 to 255
but if I use `%d` it prints:

-1 as 255

up to the number 128 is displayed correctly, larger are negative.

when I use `%u` it prints 4294967295 instead of 255.

Comment: It's probably because you're reading into a 32-bit number. Try reading into a 8-bit number instead (e.g. `char`). What code do you use to read from it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `%hhu` conversion specification:

```
printf("%hhu, ", packet[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're printing bytes, you might also consider printing hex with %02X